# What were the plans for Bad Dreams as the start of a film franchise?

Tags: horror, bad-dreams

[TV Tropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Trivia/BadDreams) mentions an unsourced claim about *[Bad Dreams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bad_Dreams_(film))* that "20th Century Fox was hoping for this to be their own supernatural horror franchise akin to A Nightmare on Elm Street, and even signed Richard Lynch on for two more additional films as a result." Is there any explanation for what the theme of the films was going to be? Was it going to be based on the original ending, which implied that the cult leader was a revenant all along?

The "Dream Cast" interviews on the DVD has Lynch mention that 20th Century Fox did *want* to sign him on for two more pictures and Jennifer Rubin mentions that she knows they wanted to spin the film out into a franchise, but Lynch stops shy of saying that he signed such a deal, and it doesn't sound like either knew of actual plans for the franchise with Rubin noting that she doesn't think that a franchise could be built off of the premise of the villain driving their victims to suicide.

Comment: I remember hearing about the plans for the franchise in the cast interviews, in a featurette on the DVD. Maybe the interview with Lynch? Unfortunately I don't have access to the DVD anymore to check  :(

Comment: Ah! Perhaps I may be able to reborrow the DVD from the library and check for that.

Comment: Quick work! @FuzzyBoots

Comment: It turned out that it was on the pile to be returned, but had not yet been returned. :)